# Get the current $_COOKIE with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible to get the current `$_COOKIE` after it has changed since the last pageload using pure PHP?

Comment: you can save it in session why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jason OOO said in the comments, you can create a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) on the server which is [tied to a cookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). You can easily modify and get up-to-date data using sessions in PHP.  Using regular cookies, this is not possible with *pure PHP* because the cookies are sent in the HTTP headers once per page view. You could easily get the updated value using client-side JavaScript that sends the cookie to the server, however.